# accessing blob properties for LastModified attribute

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am writing a little code to check the LastModified property on a blob. It seems the blob's properties is inaccessible. How can I achieve this?

Note: When debugging in Visual Studio I can see the information I need.

Below is the snippet of where I am trying to store the blob info for comparison later

```
  if (blob is CloudBlockBlob)
                {
                    var blobFileName = blob.Uri.Segments.Last().Replace("%20", " ");
                    var blobFilePath = blob.Uri.AbsolutePath.Replace(blob.Container.Uri.AbsolutePath + "/", "").Replace("%20", " ");
                    var blobPath = blobFilePath.Replace("/" + blobFileName, "");
                    var blobLM = blob.Properties.LastModified; // this is where I cannot access the LastModified poperty
                    blobInfos.Add(new BlobFileInfo
                    {
                        FileName = blobFileName,
                        BlobPath = blobPath,
                        BlobFilePath = blobFilePath,
                        Blob = blob,
                        LastModified = blobLM
                    });
                }
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say you can’t access the last modified date property?

Comment: @GauravMantri it says IListBlobItem does not contain a definition for 'Properties'...

Answer (score 1):

Please cast the `blob` as `CloudBlockBlob` and that should solve your problem.

For example:

```
if (blob is CloudBlockBlob)
{
    var cloudBlockBlob = (CloudBlockBlob) blob;
    var blobFileName = cloudBlockBlob.Uri.Segments.Last().Replace("%20", " ");
    var blobFilePath = cloudBlockBlob.Uri.AbsolutePath.Replace(cloudBlockBlob.Container.Uri.AbsolutePath + "/", "").Replace("%20", " ");
    var blobPath = blobFilePath.Replace("/" + blobFileName, "");
    var blobLM = cloudBlockBlob.Properties.LastModified; // this is where I cannot access the LastModified poperty
    blobInfos.Add(new BlobFileInfo
    {
        FileName = blobFileName,
        BlobPath = blobPath,
        BlobFilePath = blobFilePath,
        Blob = cloudBlockBlob,
        LastModified = blobLM
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Metadata and properties are not loaded by default, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-properties-metadata):

> Retrieving property and metadata values for a storage resource is a two-step process. Before you can read these values, you must explicitly fetch them by calling the FetchAttributes or FetchAttributesAsync method. The exception is if you are calling the Exists or ExistsAsync method on a resource. When you call one of these methods, Azure Storage calls the appropriate FetchAttributes method under the covers as part of the call to the Exists method.

So, perform a call like `await blob.FetchAttributesAsync();` (or any of the [overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblob.fetchattributesasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlob_FetchAttributesAsync)) before accessing the properties.

There is also a non-async [FetchAttributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblob.fetchattributes?view=azure-dotnet) if needed.